# how to hide accessibility to .php files

Tags: php

Is it normal to users can see  www.yourwebsite/php/config.php files ?In my site I can reach thoose files as a text file.And I can see which user name or table or some information about my Mysql connection.All of my files in my Xammp  htdocs folder.Are they will be also visible when I add them to some host?

Comment: No, this is not normal: Your web server must be misconfigured. Voting to migrate to serverfault.com

Comment: I am using my computer as a server.And it shows my files.

Comment: I doubt it's an emergence question, @Pekka. It's rather a "premature protection" one

Comment: @Meko what's wrong with accessing files on your own computer? You'd prefer to have no access to your own files?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: If anyone can access his config files over http, possibly containing database passwords and such, as plain text, then it is no-longer premature.

Comment: @Douglas I do not assume the OP being idiot, asking this question when their whole site is not working. If my .php files weren't parsed properly, I'd come up with totally different question.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: And neither does Douglas, the OP wrote "I can see which user name or table or some information about my Mysql connection" and this shouldn't be! So something is definitively going wrong

Comment: Let's play "Guess who's grumpy" ;-)

Comment: Maybe problem in my Xammp configuration? I downloaded it and in guide there is written that include all of your files in htdocs file.My php scripts work well.problem is when i wrote hole destination I can see my files like an ftp folder and can read my files

Comment: example of "hole destination" please, whatever it means. Exact one. you can replace a domain name only but the rest leave intact. because nobody knows here what do you mean

Comment: it cannot be any configuration problem. Because there is only 2 states: your PHP files working well OR they are visible through http daemon as text. NOT possible at the same time

Comment: @Meko: You installed xampp and then changed nothing in the configuration? Apparently you've create a directory `php/` in xampp's `htdocs/` directory. What does it contain? Is any php script in this directory working (instead of being sent as text/plain)? Is any php script in `htdocs/` working?

Comment: yes.My php files not shown in html page like and text file.but for example this is my index.html page http://localhost/kaptikacti/index.html and here when I press submit button it goes to http://localhost/kaptikacti/member/login.php page.It works but if I write only http://localhost/kaptikacti/member/ then I can see all files in this folder and I can see their codes.

Comment: I assume it's html files you are talking about?

Comment: @Volkerk yes. All them working.I can reach database add or remove data from my table

Comment: @Col.Sharpnel  this member is a folder.but when I type it  I can see all files in this folder and I can see source code of them clicking right mouse and show source code shows my <? //code ?>  all php codes

Comment: @Meko: `<? code ?>` or <?php code ?>` , the former syntax can be ignored by php.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel : Maybe, but I'm a strong believer in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark%27s_Law (no offence Meko)

Comment: sorry i deleted it because of these folks with "flag" button. The only sensible explanation that came to my mind is these files are some unused, casual ones, not involved in working process.

Answer (score 4):

Try not putting your config files in a public directory. If the content on your web server is in here:

```
/usr/meko/htdocs/php/index.php
```

you could move the config file out of the public `htdocs` folder and put it here:

```
/usr/meko/config/config.php
```

Alternatively, (and not as good), you can make sure that your config files are treated as php files, then start them with the php open tag:

```
<?php

$CONFIG["foo"] = "bar";
// config here, which never echoes anything
```

When someone accesses the php file over http through your web server, they will only see blank output.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like apache is not configured to execute your php files and is instead serving them as test/html.

You need to set up a handler to execute php files as php.

Under linux the syntax would be something like the following.
Under windows the path "modules/libphp5.so" will need to be modified to point to the php module, which might be a dll.

LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script php 
AddType text/html       php

See  http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is quite normal.
No, you can't reach those files as a text file using this address (assuming your site is functioning)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal to users can see www.yourwebsite/php/config.php files?

Yes if they are in the htdocs folder, except you deny access to the folder containing the `config.php` via a `.htaccess`-file or via the apache config. Or you move such files out of the htdocs folder.

> In my site I can reach thoose files as a text file. And I can see which user name or table or some information about my Mysql connection. All of my files in my Xammp htdocs folder.

This shouldn't happen, this seems to be a configuration Problem. It seems PHP is not working correct.

> Are they will be also visible when I add them to some host?

Yes they will be visible, but you shouldn't be able to see the php contents, if the server is configured correctly, because you shouldn't be able to see any php code in your browser, if you do there is something wrong. To make sure upload a test file to your hoster and see if you can see the php code in these files.

Answer (score 1):

As an exmaple, any wordpress installation has it's config file in the root dir. But as it don't echoes the vars there is no security issue, as long as the files are treated as PHP scripts and not text files. But it is a good idea to block direct URL access to such files through a .htaccess file password protection.